# Web Scraping using simplehtmldom on multiple sites

Tags: codeigniter, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using simplehtmldom parser for my recent web scraping project and the project is actually building a price comparing website build with CodeIgniter. The website has to fetch product names, description and price from different shopping websites. Here is my code:

```
$this->dom->load_file('http://www.site1.com');
$price1 = $this->dom->find("span[itemprop=price]");

$this->dom->load_file('http://www.site2.com');
$price2 = $this->dom->find("div.price");

$this->dom->load_file('http://www.site3.com');
$price3 = $this->dom->find("div.priceBold");

$this->dom->load_file('http://www.site4.com');
$price4 = $this->dom->find("span.fntBlack");

$this->dom->load_file('http://www.site5.com');
$price5 = $this->dom->find("div.price");
```

The above code takes approximately 15-20 seconds to load the result into the screen. When I try with only one site, it just takes 2 seconds. This is how the simplehtmldom works with multiple domains? Or is there a way to optimize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser has some [memory leak issue](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm#memory_leak), so before trying to load a new page, clear the previous one using:

```
$this->dom->clear(); 
unset($this->dom);
```

If this doesn't change anything, then one of your websites is taking much time to respond... you'll have to check one by one to find the culprit xD

Comment: you are correct! When I checked with other popular sites like yahoo, imdb and youtube, the content getting loaded pretty faster, say around 3 seconds! So, the problem with the sites that I use to scrap.